# mysql query with double join

Tags: sql, mysql

I have 3 tables, but I can only get to join another table count. See below.
The one below works like a charm, but I need to add another "count" from another table.

there is a 3rd table called "ci_nomatch" and contains a reference to ci_address_book.reference
which could have multiple entries (many on many) but I only need the count of that table.

so if ci_address_book would have an entries called "item1","item 2","item3"
and ci_nomatch would have "1,item1,user1","2,item1,user4"

I would like to have returned "2" for Item1 on the query.

Any ideas? I tried another join, but it tells me that the reference does not exist, while it does!

```
SELECT c.*, IFNULL(p.total, 0) AS matchcount
FROM ci_address_book c
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT addressbook_id, COUNT(match_id) AS total
    FROM ci_matched_sanctions
    GROUP BY addressbook_id
) AS p
ON c.id=p.addressbook_id
ORDER BY matchcount DESC
LIMIT 0,15
```

Comment: Show the code for the second join which doesn't work and we'll try and debug that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could subquery it directly in the select

```
SELECT c.*, IFNULL(p.total, 0) AS matchcount,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ci_nomatch n on n.reference = c.reference) AS othercount
FROM ci_address_book c
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT addressbook_id, COUNT(match_id) AS total
    FROM ci_matched_sanctions
    GROUP BY addressbook_id
) AS p
ON c.id=p.addressbook_id
ORDER BY matchcount DESC
LIMIT 0,15
```

@updated for comment. Including an extra column "(matchcount - othercount) AS deducted" would be best done by sub-querying.

```
SELECT *, matchcount - othercount AS deducted
FROM
(
    SELECT c.* , IFNULL( p.total, 0 ) AS matchcount, (
        SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM ci_falsepositives n
        WHERE n.addressbook_id = c.reference ) AS othercount
    FROM ci_address_book c
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT addressbook_id, COUNT( match_id ) AS total
        FROM ci_matched_sanctions GROUP BY addressbook_id ) AS p
        ON c.id = p.addressbook_id ORDER BY matchcount DESC LIMIT 0 , 15 
) S
```

Comment: [there is a 3rd table called "ci_nomatch" and contains a reference to ci_address_book.reference] - what field in ci_nomatch joins to book.reference?

Comment: I found that this worked: SELECT c . * , IFNULL( p.total, 0 ) AS matchcount, 
 (SELECT COUNT( * ) 
 FROM ci_falsepositives n
 WHERE n.addressbook_id = c.reference
 ) AS othercount
FROM ci_address_book c
LEFT JOIN 
 (SELECT addressbook_id, COUNT( match_id ) AS total
 FROM ci_matched_sanctions
 GROUP BY addressbook_id )
AS p ON c.id = p.addressbook_id
ORDER BY matchcount DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 15

Comment: now, is there a possibility to have 1 more result which is the result of: "(matchcount - othercount) AS deducted" ?

Comment: by the way... yes I know n.addressbook_id would make think that it would like to the id field of the table addressbook, but it is acutally the reference field of addressbook

Comment: i think the comment was truncated?